# Is there a way to change the build controller for many build definitions?

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

Is there a way to change the build controller for many build definitions?

I've cloned a build server and brought it on-line before deactivating its build service, thus for a very small time I had 2 build controllers, with the same name, connected to the same collection at the same time. Now I've got 900+ build defs wanting me to manually reset their build controller. Has anyone got a script, tool, trick, tip, can I go via the API etc. (I don't want to do this if possible for time reasons) to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you create a 'new' build controller, you can have it replace an existing controller, then AFAIK it should be a seamless transition from one to the other.

On your new machine, remove the existing duplicate controller, then add a new controller and select replace existing.

[image: Replace exisiting controller]

Comment: I don't think this is going to work, I'm looking for a build controller to 'adopt' orphaned build definitions aren't i?

Answer (score 0):

To change the Build Controller on multiple Build Definitions, you can use this Visual Studio Extension: [Community TFS Build Manager VS2013](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/73bf2d8e-aec6-406c-8e7f-1c678e46557f)